# I keep calling child props UP to the parent. I wand to find out the best practice

Tags: reactjs

I have created a stateless component which maps an array and returns a div with an image.(Badge)
My MAIN statefull component (obviously where the state is being held). I'm passing down a state array to badge with the details for the image.

I've then filtered the array on the MAIN component, but i need to get the index from Badge. I have passed the index from badge to main BUT I have been told this is very bad practice, please could someone tell me an alternative, or best practice.

Summary of the code below, the urlchange() take the 'indexT0Change" arg which is the index from Badge. My concern is the onClick on Badge (()=>props.url(index).
I've been told this is very bad practice

```js
// MAIN - urlChange handler
urlChange = (indexToChange) => {
    this.setState({
        teamsInfo: this.state.teams.filter((item, index) => {
            if (index === indexToChange) {
                return {
                    item
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

// MAIN - render of Badges
<Badges
    showBadges={this.state.teams}
    url={(index) => this.urlChange(index)}
/>

// BADGE
const Badges = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='badge-wrapper'>
            {props.showBadges.map((item, index) =>
                <div className='img-container'>
                    <img
                        className="badge-nav"
                        onClick={() => props.url(index)}
                        key={index}
                        id={item.team_key}
                        src={item.team_badge}
                        alt={item.team_name}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: don't see anything bad here. does that someone specified what they don't like here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so depending on the app structure, I personally don't necessarily believe that this is 'bad' practice.  You'll need to keep an eye on what causes re-renders within your component tree - since every time you re-render your parent, your children will also re-render.  You can modify your component lifecycle methods to prevent this from happening if it does (also consider using PureComponents which only perform shallow comparisons).

This is a simple example and using a HOC with a parent component maintaining state seems fine to me - (passing down the state modifying functions to the child components as props).  It essentially could easily be written as one Component - in which case you would probably deem it fine as well.

If the information here is constrained to these components, I'd say stick with this HOC approach.  If you foresee additional complexity in the future where you need to expose these components elsewhere - you may want to look into React Hooks such as [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response. I have always done it this way but have been todl this is bad practice!I've only recently touched base with hooks, not yet seen the useContext one,So i'll take a look. Appreciate your detailed response